# Jquery Draggable and Stack and sec. CLass?

Tags: jquery, stack, draggable

I have a little problem with the jQuery UI Stack

```
$('.dra').draggable({ addClasses: false, containment: 'window', zIndex: '9999', stack: '.sta'});
```

The problem is that all DIVs with the class .dra are with stack. But i only want all div with the class .dra and with the second class .sta with stack.

or must i say

```
$('.dra .sta').draggable({ addClasses: false, containment: 'window', zIndex: '9999', stack: '.sta'});
$('.dra').draggable({ addClasses: false, containment: 'window', zIndex: '9999'});
```

i dont understand it. For what is the value after stack: ?

Can anybody help me?
kind regards
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only `class="dra sta"` and not *all* `.sta` elements, then you need to use both classes in the selector, you can do that by leaving no space between the [`.class` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
$('.dra').draggable({ 
  addClasses: false, 
  containment: 'window', 
  zIndex: '9999', 
  stack: '.dra.sta'
});
```

If you don't have a space, it only matches elements with *both* classes.  You need a specific selector here because it's not checking against the `.dra` elements only, but rather using that text literally as the selector, with no restriction (for example the above translates to `$('.dra.sta')`), [you can see the source here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L770).

Comment: Hi Nick,
thanx for the fast answer.

dra = draggable
sta = stack

all DIVs with class dra are draggable and when the div has the second class sta = draggable with stack

This code work

     $('.dra.sta').draggable({ 
       addClasses: false, 
       containment: 'window', 
       zIndex: '9999', 
       stack: '.dra.sta'
     });
     
     
     $('.dra').draggable({ 
       addClasses: false, 
       containment: 'window', 
       zIndex: '9999'
     });

Is this way ok? 

greetz from Germany

PS: I hope u understand what i mean .. my english is not so good ;)

Comment: @Peter - That should work just fine, if my understanding of what you *want* is correct.  Though, I'm not 100% clear on your intentions from the description...if you had a link I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: ok, nice :)

coz i thought the class ".dra" is than double draggable. 
Thx 4 the rly fast help and have a nice day :)

Comment: @Peter - Welcome :) If this resolved your issue be sure to accept the answer via the checkmark on the left...if it didn't please post what problem you're still having :)